# Bootstrap Mobile versions have space on the right side, container is also not proper size. have overflow-x:hidden.. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, whitespace

Bootstrap Mobile versions have space on the right side, container is also not proper size. have overflow-x:hidden..

I also double checked the container and rows to make sure the containers divs are all closed and there are no nested containers, or containers inside of rows.

You can view a sample here: http://holbrookautoparts.com/mock/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your input

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control input-lg text-center font-heavy" id="contact-email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
```

```css
@media (max-width: 568px)
style.css:932
.signupform input[type="email"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
```

change width to 100%;

and maybe the img, maybe add img-responsive.

This block made this problem in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.signupform` css at line number 980 as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 414px){
  .signupform {
    top: 100px;
    left: 43px;
    width: auto;
    right: 43px;
  }
}
```